# Small shrub ID needed

Tags: identification

The pictured evergreen shrub was planted in Seattle about ten or twelve years ago. It was about 2 feet high at the time, and is now about 4 ft. high by 3 ft. wide, so is rather slow-growing. It blooms in late March, as shown in second photo. There is little to no scent in the flowers or leaves.

[image: small shrub]

[image: small shrub closeup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Tasmannia lanceolata (Drimys lanceolata / Pepper Bush) which seems to fit geographical location and morphological appearance, except for the fact that the OP claims no aroma from leaves. Is it possible that the aroma emerges from dried leaves I wonder?

Comment: I chanced to see some new potted shrubs being planted recently, and they looked very much like the plant in question. The labels did indeed say "Drimys lanceolata". I visited my shrub yesterday and tasted a leaf. A very peppery taste resulted eventually, so BINGO! I never thought to sample a leaf before, due to the total absence of scent.

Answer (score 0):

Abelia X grandifolia.  Used to be called   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnaea_%C3%97_grandiflora

[Abelia images](https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrS_AkEjeJauTYAXxFXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEyOWVocHF1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDQjM5MTZfMQRzZWMDc2M-?p=abelia%20X%20gandifolia&fr=mcafee#id=0&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdavisla.files.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F11%2Fabelia-x-grandiflora.jpg&action=click)  Your pictures sure look similar...

REVISION;  Try a similar plant; Skimmia japonica..[Skimmia japonica](https://static.ashwoodnurseries.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/k/skimmia_japonica_tansley_green_3_resized.jpg)

Comment: No, abelia flowers are more tubular and the leaves are different as well.

Comment: Oh my goodness, this isn't Daphne is it?

Comment: Daphne odora...does it smell almost too intoxicating?  https://shadygardens.files.wordpress.com/2007/11/daphnenewphoto.jpg

Comment: @stormy: I wish. Daphne-scented air is the best air. I updated question.

Comment: I knew you would know that smell...on wards!